# Annotate queryset with percentage grouped by date

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-orm, django-annotate

Suppose I have the following model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default=DEFAULT_CHOICE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I need to annotate an `Order` queryset with the percentage of each `category` grouped by month (based on the `created_at` field). I managed to write a query to count every `Order` grouped by month:

```
orders_per_month = (Order.objects
    .annotate(month=TruncMonth('created_at'))
    .values('month')
    .annotate(count=Count('id'))
    .order_by('month')
    .values('month', 'count')
)
```

Changing just the last `.values()` to `.values('month', 'category', 'count')`, I can get the count grouped by both `category` and `month`.

Is it possible to get the percentage of each `category` grouped by month using Django's ORM? For example, if I had the following data:

```
MONTH | CATEGORY
Jan   | 'A'
Jan   | 'B'
Feb   | 'A'
```

I would like to get something similar to this:

```
[
    (Jan, 'A', 0.5),
    (Jan, 'B', 0.5),
    (Feb, 'A', 1),
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get this figured out?  You should look into the Windows functions. You can use a partition argument to do calculations. (1) window partition over month and count, (2) partition over month and category and count, and (3) divide steps 1 and 2. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Django's [Window functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions), as suggested by @ac2001 in the comments, I managed to get what I needed.

Using the example model and supposing I want the percentage of each `category` grouped by month:

```
orders_per_month = (Order.objects
    .annotate(month=TruncMonth('created_at'))
    .values('month', 'category')
    .distinct()
    .annotate(month_total=Window(
        expression=Count('id'),
        partition_by=[F('month')],
    ))
    .annotate(month_category=Window(
        expression=Count('id'),
        partition_by=[F('month'), F('category')],
    ))
    .annotate(percentage=ExpressionWrapper(
        F('month_category') * 100.0 / F('month_total'),
        output_field=FloatField()
    ))
    .values('month', 'percentage', 'category')
)
```

Any suggestions on simplifying this further are welcome.